# How to get children of a WPF container by type?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

How can I get the child controls of type `ComboBox` in `MyContainer` `Grid` in WPF?

```
<Grid x:Name="MyContainer">                    
    <Label Content="Name"  Name="label1"  />
    <Label Content="State" Name="label2"  />
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="comboBox1"/>
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="comboBox3" />
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="comboBox4" />
</Grid>
```

This line gives me an error:

```
var myCombobox = this.MyContainer.Children.GetType(ComboBox);
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

This extension method will search recursively for child elements of the desired type:

```
public static T GetChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) 
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null) return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

So using that you can ask for `MyContainer.GetChildOfType<ComboBox>()`.

Comment: `LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(DependencyObject depObj, string elementName)` worked for me to achieve the same goal.

Comment: For me, this extension method worked, while the suggested LogicalTreeHelper way in the comment above - did not.

Comment: I keep getting null

Answer (score 48):

Children is a collection of UIElements. So you need to iterate over the items and determine for each item whether it is of the required type. Fortunately, there is already a Linq method for exactly this, namely [`Enumerable.OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx), which you can conveniently call using [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) syntax:

```
var comboBoxes = this.MyContainer.Children.OfType<ComboBox>();
```

This method filters the collection based on their type and returns, in your case, only the elements of type `ComboBox`.

If you only want the first ComboBox (as your variable name might suggest), you can just append a call to [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) to the query:

```
var myComboBox = this.MyContainer.Children.OfType<ComboBox>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This will not search in `ContentControl

Answer (score 12):

All of these answers but one uses recursion which **IMO** is just lame :)

**Get visual children:**

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>([NotNull] this DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (parent == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parent));

    var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>(new[] {parent});

    while (queue.Any())
    {
        var reference = queue.Dequeue();
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(reference);

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(reference, i);
            if (child is T children)
                yield return children;

            queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
}
```

**Get logical children:**

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindLogicalChildren<T>([NotNull] this DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (parent == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parent));

    var queue = new Queue<DependencyObject>(new[] {parent});

    while (queue.Any())
    {
        var reference = queue.Dequeue();
        var children = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(reference);
        var objects = children.OfType<DependencyObject>();

        foreach (var o in objects)
        {
            if (o is T child)
                yield return child;

            queue.Enqueue(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that both deeply traverse trees, if you wish to stop at first encounter then change both codes to encompass the call to `queue.Enqueue` in an `else` block.

Comment: why recursion is lame?

Comment: @Konrad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72209/recursion-or-iteration

Comment: I like it it looks quite elegant

Comment: @Konrad 907 days later...  recursion is lame because you can exhaust the stack 

Comment: @aybe Lol. Yeah in C# that's true because it has no tail call optimization. In F# and many other languages it's actually a preferred way.

Comment: Yep Yep Yep :)))

Comment: Ok, so how do you actually call the above?

Comment: That's an extension method so `your object.Method()`.

Answer (score 3):

All of these answers are very nice, but, if you're trying to find a *specific* visual child of type T, you're either stuck getting them all and then finding the one you want, or hoping the first one you get is the one you want.  I merged a few approaches to find a specific one based on a criteria.  It's a bit like LINQ, but I didn't want to try to deal with a recursive enumerator.

Use it like this:

```
MyContainer.FirstOrDefaultChild<Label>(l => l.Content=="State")
```

I wrote it as an extension method.

```
public static class DependencyObjectExtensions
{
    public static T FirstOrDefaultChild<T>(this DependencyObject parent, Func<T, bool> selector) 
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        T foundChild;
        return FirstOrDefaultVisualChildWhere(parent, selector, out foundChild) ? foundChild : default(T);
    }

    private static bool FirstOrDefaultVisualChildWhere<T>(DependencyObject parent, Func<T, bool> selector,
        out T foundChild) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            var tChild = child as T;
            if (tChild != null)
            {
                if (!selector(tChild)) continue;
                foundChild = tChild;
                return true;
            }

            if (FirstOrDefaultVisualChildWhere(child, selector, out foundChild))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        foundChild = default(T);
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Search for the first child of a certain type that includes a predetermined point (of Screen):

(param 'point' is the result of calling 'PointToScreen' function (declared in Visual type)  )

```
private TDescendantType FindDescendant<TDescendantType>(DependencyObject parent, Point screenPoint) 
         where TDescendantType : DependencyObject
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        if (child is Visual)
        {
            Point point = ((Visual)child).PointFromScreen(screenPoint);
            Rect rect = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds((Visual)child);

            if (!rect.Contains(point))
                continue;
        }

        if (child is TDescendantType)
        {
            return (TDescendantType)child;
        }

        child = FindDescendant<TDescendantType>(child, screenPoint);
        if (child != null)
        {
            return (TDescendantType)child;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score -2):

I found this working example:

```
foreach (object o in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(myWindow))
{
    if (o is SomeTypeOfMine)
    {
      //do something
    }
}
```

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e0be708a-5fa2-4479-b5a0-8ff44a963803/find-all-child-controls-of-a-type?forum=wpf