# get all check boxes in a UserControl - WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, checkbox, user-controls

I have declared checkboxes in a grid layout in XAML on a UserControl.

```
<CheckBox Content="Boo" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
<CheckBox Content="Hoo" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

I want to somehow iterate over all these checkboxes in C#.
How would I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279092/how-to-get-children-of-a-wpf-container-by-type) might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There souldn't be the need to access them programatically. You should use a ViewModel and bind properties to the checkboxes.

```
public class SomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isCheckBoxOneChecked;

    public bool IsCheckBoxOneChecked
    {
        get { return isCheckBoxOneChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(isCheckBoxOneChecked))
            {
                return;
            }

            isCheckBoxOneChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckBoxOneChecked}" Content="Boo" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
<CheckBox Content="Hoo" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

---

You also have to set the `DataContext` like this:

```
this.DataContext = new SomeViewModel();
```

That's also possible via xaml.

Then you simply set the `IsCheckBoxOneChecked` property to true and the checkbox gets checked automatically. If the user unchecks the checkbox the property also gets set to false and vice versa.

---

Take a look over here: [Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) Explained](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained)

---

Nevertheless, if you set the `Name` property of your `Grid` you can iterate over all children:

```
// Grid is named 'MyGrid'
foreach (var child in this.MyGrid.Children)
{
    if (child is CheckBox)
    {
        var checkBox = child as CheckBox;

        // Do awesome stuff with the checkbox
    }
}
```