# Get Children of Children

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get tge `amob:AmobCombobox` but it is inside of another stack panel.

If I do`ToolStackLeft.Children[i]` I get the stackpanels objects. I wanted something like

```
if (ToolStackLeft.Children[i].Children is AmobComboBox)
{
   //DO SOMETHING
}
```

My Code

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
     <Label Content="5-" Foreground="White" Margin="0,-2,0,0"/>
     <amob:AmobComboBox x:Name="cmbTool10" Width="430" Margin="0,0,35,20" SelectionChanged="cmbTool10_SelectionChanged"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @Liam how do you format the code like that?

Comment: What technology is this? What's a AmobCombobox? Is this WPF?

Comment: AmobCombobox is a custom Combobox. Nothing special. Yes, this is WPF

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: WPF, web forms, windows forms, what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get children of a WPF container by type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279092/how-to-get-children-of-a-wpf-container-by-type)

Comment: As a passing comment - I just did a google search on AmobCombobox - only results were questions asked here by user sdadad & qweqeqwe - any relation??.