# How to find WPF expander children programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf

## Heading

I have programmatically added an `Expander`, `Grid`, and some other Controls.
Now I want to get the `StackPanels` Children which is in the `Grid` of `Expanders` Content.

```
Expander
  Grid
    StackPanel
      TextBox
```

How I can access to `TextBox.Text` ?

For `StackPanel` i would use

```
List<StackPanel = mypanel.Children.OfType<StackPanel>.ToList();
```

Super easy. But i can't access to `Expander` Content in that way.

```
List<Grid> = expander.Content.OfType<Grid>.ToList();
```

doesn't work.

Thanks to mm8 i fixed my problem as follows:

```
Grid grid = editable_expander.Content as Grid;
                List<StackPanel> stackpanel = grid.Children.OfType<StackPanel>().ToList();
                for(int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    StackPanel sp = stackpanel[i];
                    List<TextBox> textbox = sp.Children.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
                    for(int j = 0; j < textbox.Count; j++)
                    {
                        TextBox tb1 = textbox[j];
                        length = Convert.ToInt32(tb1.Text);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get children of a WPF container by type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279092/how-to-get-children-of-a-wpf-container-by-type)

Comment: @Sinatr doesn't work.

Comment: Recursive solution lookup for children in visual tree from duplicate should give you a possibility to use either parent to find `TextBox` and then access its `Text` property. *"Doesn't work"* -  can't do anything about it, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the `Content` property:

```
Grid grid = expander.Content as Grid;
```

Comment: That works for me thanks. Don't know which Person is disliking all answers here but thanks for your solution. Didnt thought to make it this way..

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Grid gr;
StackPanel sp;
TextBox tb;
...
gr = ex.Content as Grid;
sp = gr.Children[0] as StackPanel;
tb = sp.Children[0] as TextBlock;
//reversed 
...
sp = tb.Parent as StackPanel;
gr = sp.Parent as Grid;
ex = gr.Parent as Expander;
```