# Set event to button when created via XAML string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, dynamically-generated

I got the following code, is going to be a dynamically generated grid:

```
string xaml = "<Grid Margin='8 8 0 0' Width='175'>" +
                "<Grid.RowDefinitions>" +
                    "<RowDefinition Height='115'/>" +
                    "<RowDefinition Height='*'/>" +
                    "<RowDefinition Height='Auto'/>" +
                "</Grid.RowDefinitions>" +
                "<Image Source='C:/Users/SaFteiNZz/Curro/yo2.png' Height='115' Width='171' Stretch='Uniform'/>" +
                "<Button x:Name='BtnEditAc' Grid.Row='0' Style='{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniAccentButton}' HorizontalAlignment='Right' VerticalAlignment='Bottom' Margin='0,0,16,-20'>" +
                    "<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind='AccountSettingsVariant' Width='30' Height='30' Margin='0,0,0,5'/>" +
                "</Button>" +
                "<StackPanel Grid.Row='1' Margin='8,24,8,8'>" +
                    "<TextBlock TextWrapping='Wrap' FontWeight='Bold'>Pablo Antonio Hernandez Hernandez</TextBlock>" +
                    "<TextBlock TextWrapping='Wrap' VerticalAlignment='Center'>46080696N</TextBlock>" +
                "</StackPanel>" +
                "<Border BorderBrush='White' BorderThickness='1' CornerRadius='0' Grid.Row='0' Grid.RowSpan='3'>" +
                    "<Border.Effect>" +
                        "<DropShadowEffect BlurRadius='10' Direction='-90' Color='Black' ShadowDepth='0'/>" +
                    "</Border.Effect>" +
                "</Border>" +
            "</Grid>";

UIElement element = (UIElement)XamlReader.Parse(xaml, context);
empDisplay.Children.Add(element);
```

**Like that the code works.**

But I want to **set a click event** to the **button (*BtnEditAc*)** which if I do directly in the XAML string procs an error(Couldn't create a click from text BtnEditAc_Click or something like that).

---

Is there a way to set the click event for that button? or connect to a function somehow?

I'm about to make it using CLR objects coded instead of XamlReader, but first I want to know if there's a solution for this.

Hope you know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You could navigate the tree (or find button by name) and add a delegate to click event. I think that you can't do it directly from the string...where would you put the code of the event handler?

Comment: @Babbillumpa the event handler is just below the function that contains that, in the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if this solution could work:

```
//Here you have the grid
Grid element = (Grid)XamlReader.Parse(xaml, context);
//Now try to get the button
Button btn = (Button)element.FindName("BtnEditAc");
if(btn != null)
{
    btn.Click  += new RoutedEventHandler(OnBtnEditAcClick);
}
```

Where `OnBtnEditAcClick` is the event handler.
Then add the element to your main view:

```
empDisplay.Children.Add(element);
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Nothing, take a look also at the other answer, he added the case in which you don't know the name of your control and find it navigating the visual tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse Command binding from xml instead of Click events:

```
<Button x:Name='BtnEditAc' Command='{Binding MyCommand}' Grid.Row='0' ...
```

If for some reason you don't want to use commands, you may manually add click event in code, if only you can find the `Button` in the `xaml` element you just parsed. For example, if you know the root element in your serialized xaml will be `Grid`:

```
Grid rootElement = (Grid)XamlReader.Parse(xaml, context);
grdMain.Children.Add(rootElement);
Button btn = (Button)rootElement.FindName("BtnEditAc");
btn.Click += btn_Click;
```

Or:

```
UIElement elem = (UIElement)XamlReader.Parse(xaml, context);
Button b =(Button) LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(elem, "BtnEditAc");
```

As an alternative, if you don't know the type of root element you can use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759923/891715) to find it by name & type:

```
    public static T FindChild<T>(this DependencyObject parent, string childName)
       where T : DependencyObject
    {
        // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
        if (parent == null) return null;

        T foundChild = null;

        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            // If the child is not of the request child type child
            T childType = child as T;
            if (childType == null)
            {
                // recursively drill down the tree
                foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                if (foundChild != null) break;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
            {
                var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                // If the child's name is set for search
                if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                {
                    // if the child's name is of the request name
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // child element found.
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
        }

        return foundChild;
    }
```

or if you don't know the name of your button, you can for example get the first child of type Button (or implement a method that will return all children of a given type) with [this extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10279201/891715):

```
    public static T GetChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj == null) return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

            var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If you want to set your event handler in xaml and parse it manually, I don't know if it can be done.

Comment: Yes command binding was one of my alternatives, "grid.FindName()" has ended up being the shortest and easiest way in this case. Thank you for showing more alternatives and cases.