# How do I get children of a component 2 layers deep in a WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm building a WPF app with a StackPanel of Grids with TextBoxes in them. I need a list of all the TextBoxes. How do I reach two levels deep using Children.OfType() function?

Already tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10279201/9985476 but didn't seem to work. Maybe I implemented it wrong?

Sample code:

```
  <StackPanel x:Name="addEmployees">
    <Grid>
      <TextBox Text="" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
      <TextBox Text="" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
      <TextBox Text="" />
    </Grid>
  <StackPanel />
```

In my code behind i tried something of this sort:

```cs
private IEnumerable<TextBox> addEmployeesTB = addEmployees.Children.OfType<Grid>().Children.OfType<TextBox>();
```

But i get: CS1061  C# does not contain a definition for 'Children' and no accessible extension method 'Children' accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You're working with wpf in a very inefficient way. Making things hard for yourself. Instead of adding controls in code you should bind a collection of viewmodels and template that out into ui. Repeated controls - think itemscontrol. You then don't need to find the children of the child you first added... You just work with the data in the bound collection. Usually an observablecollection. Everyone uses mvvm because it's easily the best way to work. It will seem strange at first but that's just because it's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addEmployees.Children.OfType<Grid>()` gives you an `IEnumerable` of `Grid`, not a single `Grid`.

So we can't just "dot" them out. Assuming every list of `Grid` has a number of `TextBox` children, we have to flatten them out with LINQ `SelectMany`.

This is how `SelectMany` works. You have a list of `Grid`, and each `Grid` has a list of `TextBox`.

```
Grid1
    TextBox1
    TextBox2
Grid2
    TextBox3
Grid3
    TextBox4
    TextBox5
```

We can use `SelectMany` to turn them into

```
TextBox1
TextBox2
TextBox3
TextBox4
TextBox5
```

Here's my attempt at your code:

```
private IEnumerable<TextBox> addEmployeesTB = addEmployees.Children.OfType<Grid>()
            .SelectMany(grid => grid.Children.OfType<TextBox>())
            .ToList();
```

It should look like this:
[image]

Here is LINQ [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) documentation.

Please let me know if it works.