# WPF ScrollViewer horizontal scrolling with buttons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a ListBox with horizontal orientation inside a ScrollViewer. When the list grows, it automatically scrolls to the last element. The scrollbars work, however must be disabled for this. I need to have separate buttons which would scroll the ScrollViewer by a predetermined iteration (much like buttons on the scrollbars). For this, I have tried:

```
sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(sv.HorizontalOffset + 20);
```

However, the ScrollViewer's HorizontalOffset seems to always be 0, and the method doesn't do anything with any values.

```
sv.LineRight();
sv.LineLeft();
```

both don't work, probably because the only child element is the ListBox.
If I change the ListBox's orientation to vertical, then the ScrollViewer's VerticalOffset changes with scrolling/adding new elements, and ScrollToVerticalOffset works correctly. Why is this different with horizontal orientation? Any other solutions?

Note: this was done without using XAML to place the controls.

Comment: "*ListBox ... inside a ScrollViewer*" does not seem to make sense in the first place. ListBox already supports scrolling. And it has a ScrollIntoView method.

Comment: @Clemens thank you, but the idea is that I need to move the scrolling position by a set number of pixels, not just scroll to an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work, you need to do a couple things:

Remove the outer `ScrollViewer` and just use the `ScrollViewer` that is built into the `ListBox`.

On the ListBox set the following properties:

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
```

This will make the `HorizontalOffset` property work in pixels. When it is set to `True` it works in items.

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
```

This will keep scrolling active but will hide the scrollbar.

In your code you can get the `ScrollViewer` of the `ListBox` like so. In this example my `ListBox` is named `x:Name="ListBox"`.

```
var scrollViewer = ListBox.FindChildByType<ScrollViewer>();
```

Finally, you can set the offset like below. In my sample, I created a method and passed in a value from my button click event handlers.

```
private void ScrollHorizontally(double offset)
{
    var scrollViewer = ListBox.FindChildByType<ScrollViewer>();

    scrollViewer?.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset + offset);
}
```

Comment: My ListBox does not contain a method "FindChildByType". Are you using a library of some sort?

Comment: This answer has a method you could use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279092/how-to-get-children-of-a-wpf-container-by-type